# Playing a part of video using SMIL on iPad

Tags: ipad, iis, html5-video, smil, smooth-streaming

I have an IIS Server with Smooth Streaming Media Services installed and a video file, f.e. it length equal 100.
Have SMIL markup any parameter or something another to next case:

1. I set SMIL file as a source if html5 video tag
2. In SMIL I set attributes like offset and duration
3. Video plays from 20 second to 50 and html5 video controls should show that video length is 30 seconds
4. It should works on iPad

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based on answer found here: [Does iPhone support SMIL in incoming MMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451260/does-iphone-support-smil-in-incoming-mms) indicate that Apple doesn't really care about or implement SMIL as a standard, whether in MMS, or browser.